# Netbeans vs VSC

Tags: netbeans, ide, editor, visual-studio-code

I'm using NetBeans. 
In NetBeans, just drag a *css* or *js* file from the file manager section and drop between **head** tags...
your link and script tags are inserted.

Is this feature available in **VSC**?

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported as of VSCode 1.15. We are tracking the feature request here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/10895